# Bad \neq with sfmath and uncommon sf font

Tags: sfmath

I need to use Alegreya Sans as main font and sf math, accomplished in pdflatex with `\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}` and `\usepackage{sfmath}`. However, equal sign = taken from Alegreya Sans does not match well with `\not`, so `\neq` becomes ugly.

How to set = to standard math alfabets, like `\equiv`, or alternatively fix just `\neq` command?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{sfmath}

\begin{document}
not ok: $a \neq b$

ok: $a \not \equiv b$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: display \neq with sfmath and Alegreya Sans]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way, implementing the negation with a slash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sfmath}

% these declarations are missing from sfmath.sty
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{SFMathUp}{`=}
\DeclareMathSymbol{/}{\mathord}{SFMathUp}{`/}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\neg@te}[2]{%
  \vphantom{/#2}%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1/$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\neq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\neg@te{=}}}
\RenewCommandCopy{\ne}{\neq}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\neq b$ $a\ne b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @egreg!

Answer (score 1):

Definition of `\neq` is as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\ne{\not=}
```

Source: [`source2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e) code line no. 412 and p. 519 (2021/12/09)

This means it adds `\not` character on the `=` character provided by that font. Therefore it looks weird. `\not` command might not be suitable for the shape of `=` in each font. You can use LuaLaTeX to get the correct shape from the selected font, but you would need to declare `\neq` as a text command. See the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{AlegreyaSans}
\DeclareTextCommand{\neq}{TU}{\symbol{"2260}}

\begin{document}
$\neq$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use this solution when I use LuaLaTeX. This time I want to keep pdfLaTeX.