# Bad \Longrightarrow with sfmath and uncommon sf font

Tags: fonts, arrows, sfmath

I need to use Alegreya Sans as main font and sf math, accomplished in pdflatex with `\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}` and `\usepackage{sfmath}`.

It seams `\Longrightarrow` is a composition of `=` and `\Rightarrow`.  This is recipe for disaster if fonts for these chars do not match, like in my case. Can someone help me to fix `\Longrightarrow` and `\implies`, maybe by using CM = only with these arrows?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \implies
\usepackage{sfmath}

\begin{document}

$a = b \implies c \Longrightarrow d$

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: bad arrows]

Ps: a related question to my document: [Bad \neq with sfmath and uncommon sf font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615096/bad-neq-with-sfmath-and-uncommon-sf-font)

Comment: `sfmath` doesn't actually change many symbols, but it changes `=`, on which `\Longrightarrow` is based. Are you happy if `\Longrightarrow` is the same as in Computer Modern?

Comment: @egreg, yes, I would be happy if \Longrightarrow is the dá-me as CM, keeping normal uses of = as sf.

Comment: I am also happy with any good looking \Longrightarrow that keeps proper space with surrounding elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a math alphabet for OT1/cmr/m/n and define a command for the equal sign for that font.  Looking inside \Longrightarrow, we see that new equal must be put inside \Relbar. full solution on MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \implies
\usepackage{sfmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{FooFont}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fooEqual}{\mathrel}{FooFont}{`=}
\renewcommand{\Relbar}{\mathrel\fooEqual}

\begin{document}

$a = b \implies c \Longrightarrow d$

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result from MWE]

Comment: You can accept own answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Zarko.

Comment: Rationale for the solution: from log file, for sfmath we read several font replacement comments like
"LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font 'operators' in version 'normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/AlegreyaSans-LF/m/n on input line 3 29."

Reading sfmath.sty code, we get example for declaration for fonts like
"\DeclareSymbolFont{SFMath}{\math@encoding}{\math@sfdefault}{m}{sl}
...
\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{SFMath}{`A}"

Reading content of \Longrightarrow with \show reveals what forms the long arrow.